# How to upgrade python 2.7.12 to python 2.7.14 in Ubuntu?

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04

I am not able to upgrade the python version in Ubuntu. What is the command used for this? Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then download using the following command:

```
version=2.7.13
cd ~/Downloads/
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/$version/Python-$version.tgz
```

Extract and go to the directory:

```
tar -xvf Python-$version.tgz
cd Python-$version
```

Now, install using the command you just tried, using checkinstall instead to make it easier to uninstall if needed:

```
./configure
sudo make install
```

This worked for me..

Comment: I had to remove python from /usr/local/lib/ first

Comment: But all the packages are in /usr/local/lib, aren't they?